# Udp messaging server c++, communication between two clients

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have a problem on communication between two udp client via udp server(a->server->b).
First I save the clients's address_in to a hashmap, Then client a send to client b some messages. Every thing is right(I logged the flow of communicating) except that server only send message to current requested client(client a) while using address of client b. Here is my code:

```
private:
        std::map<int, sockaddr_in> ids_clients;
        static int socket;

        static void sig_handler(int signo) {
                if (signo == SIGKILL) {
                        close(socket);
                        printf("stopped\n");
                }
        }

        void monitor() {
                int count;
                socklen_t addr_size = sizeof (sockaddr_in);
                struct sockaddr_in address;
                std::map<int, sockaddr_in>::iterator client_it;
                Buffer buffer;
                Message message;
                while (true) {
                        buffer.reset();
                        if ((count = recvfrom(socket, buffer.getBuffer(), buffer.getCapacity(), MSG_TRUNC, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addr_size)) == -1) {
                                perror("network error!\n");
                                break;
                        }
                        if (count > message.getHeaderSize()) {
                                message.deserialize(&buffer, count);
                                int id = message.getTag();
                                printf("id: %d\n", id);
                                switch (message.getType()) {
                                        case Message::Type::CONN:
                                        {
                                                //Save client address
                                                printf("SOCK: %d, ID: %d, IP: %s, PORT: %d\n", socket, id, inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), address.sin_port);
                                                ids_clients[id] = address;
                                                message.setTag(Message::Code::OK);
                                                message.serialize(&buffer);
                                                if (sendto(socket, buffer.getBuffer(), buffer.getSize(), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &address, addr_size) == -1) {
                                                        ids_clients.erase(ids_clients.find(id));
                                                        printf("Authenticated - client: %s:%d: could not response!\n", inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port));
                                                        continue;
                                                }
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        case Message::Type::MEDIA:
                                        {
                                                //Send from current client to the client has id = message.getTag();
                                                printf("SOCK: %d, ID: %d, IP: %s, PORT: %d\n", socket, id, inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), address.sin_port);
                                                if (message.getChannel() == Message::Channel::SINGLE) {
                                                        client_it = ids_clients.find(id);
                                                        if (client_it != ids_clients.end()) {
                                                                printf("ID: %d, IP: %s, PORT: %d\n", message.getSeqNo(), inet_ntoa(client_it->second.sin_addr), client_it->second.sin_port);
                                                                printf("SOCK: %d, SRC ID:%d, TO ID: %d\n", socket, message.getSeqNo(), id);
                                                                message.serialize(&buffer);
                                                                if (sendto(socket, buffer.getBuffer(), buffer.getSize(), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &(client_it->second), sizeof (client_it->second)) == -1) {
                                                                        ids_clients.erase(client_it);
                                                                        printf("Media package - client: %s:%d: could not reach!\n", inet_ntoa(client_it->second.sin_addr), ntohs(client_it->second.sin_port));
                                                                        continue;
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                        } else {
                                //echo server
                                sendto(socket, buffer.getBuffer(), count, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &address, addr_size);
                        }
                }
        }
public:

        void start(int port) {
                signal(SIGKILL, sig_handler);
                struct sockaddr_in sin;
                socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
                int mps = PGK_MAX_SIZE;
                if (setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &mps, sizeof (mps)) == -1) {
                        perror("SO_RCVBUF\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                memset(&sin, 0, sizeof (sin));
                sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
                sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
                sin.sin_port = htons(port);
                if (bind(socket, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (sin))) {
                        perror("bind()\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                printf("started: port %d\n", port);
                monitor();
                close(socket);
                printf("stopped\n");
        }
};
int Server::socket;
```

Please help,
Thank you!

Comment: coming up with a smaller reproducable test case would make it easier for others to help you.  There's a lot of extraneous code here to wade through for other people to help you with a specific problem.

Comment: reducing the indentation to no more than 4 spaces would also be very helpful

Comment: Why don't you add the code for Message, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count > message.getHeaderSize()) {
```

if this is false, doesn't it fall through to:

```
//echo server
sendto(socket, buffer.getBuffer(), count, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &address, addr_size);
```

which just sends it back?

We're missing a LOT of code.  You need to come up with a small, self contained reproduceable test case if you want people to help you.  Please see the link below for help putting that together.

http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hi xaxxon, thank you for your help. But my code pass if (count > message.getHeaderSize()) condition, and log "SOCK: 3, SRC ID:2, TO ID: 1
id: 1
SOCK: 3, ID: 1, IP: 171.241.192.35, PORT: 1260
ID: 2, IP: 118.102.7.146, PORT: 1477
SOCK: 3, SRC ID:2, TO ID: 1
id: 1
SOCK: 3, ID: 1, IP: 171.241.192.35, PORT: 1260
ID: 2, IP: 118.102.7.146, PORT: 1477
SOCK: 3, SRC ID:2, TO ID: 1
"
Every thing work fine, but message did not send to client b but client a!!

Comment: message.getHeaderSize() is a constant, just a simple test so I did not use a static field

Comment: please provide all the logs in the question - the ones showing the clients connect -- and make sure to put it in a source block so it's easy to read

Comment: I could not answer before 7h last :(.

Comment: Comment out this line: printf("id: %d\n", id);
1. Connect:
int id = message.getTag(); //id of connection
printf("SOCK: %d, ID: %d, IP: %s, PORT: %d\n", socket, id, inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), address.sin_port);
2. Communicate:
printf("SOCK: %d, SrcID: %d, IP: %s, PORT: %d\n", socket, message.getSeqNo(), inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), address.sin_port);

if (client_it != ids_clients.end()) {
    printf("ID: %d, IP: %s, PORT: %d\n", message.getSeqNo(), inet_ntoa(client_it->second.sin_addr), client_it->second.sin_port);
}

Comment: 1. Log info:
 - Connect:
SOCK: 3, ID: 2, IP: 118.102.7.146, PORT: 54195
SOCK: 3, ID: 1, IP: 118.102.7.146, PORT: 32201
- Communicate:
SOCK: 3, SrcID: 1, IP: 118.102.7.146, PORT: 32201
DstID: 2, IP: 118.102.7.146, PORT: 54195